# D365FO entity not exposed via oData

Tags: odata, microsoft-dynamics

I'm currently writing an integration app which transfers data from D365 FinOps and our legacy system.  I'm using the oData API.

I would like to insert records into the Product Relationships entity but it doesn't seem to be exposed to oData.

Is there anything I can do in the D365 FinOps application to expose this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You make a copy of the entity and make that public.

Comment: I assume you mean this is not possible using the FinOps app.  Could you explain more about how you copy an entity and make it public?

Comment: No, it is not possible via UI, you need a developer who does this: https://dhruvrthakar.blogspot.com/2019/06/how-to-create-duplicate-data-entity-in.html and then gives the new entity PublicCollectionName and PublicEntityName non-empty properties.